# как собрать сообщение в телеграм

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Всем привет не могу понять как решить такую задачу на Python
Есть два списка:

```
list1 = [('значение поля профиль',), ('значение поля фамилия',), ('значение поля город',)]
```

и

```
list2 = ['профиль', 'фамилия', 'город']
```

в двух списках значения только string, значения берутся из БД SQLite
задача отправить в одном сообщении в телеграмм текст вида:

```
профиль: значение поля профиль
фамилия: значение поля фамилия
город: значение поля город
```

Comment: ну банально через `f` строчку пройтись и соеденить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А можно упаковать два листа как один через `zip` и отформатировать их в один лист строк, далее уже его упаковать как одну строку с переносами.

```
list1 = [('значение поля профиль',),
         ('значение поля фамилия',),
         ('значение поля город',)]

list2 = ['профиль', 'фамилия', 'город']

# Создаем пустой список для хранения строк
result_list = []

# Итерируемся по элементам list2 и list1 одновременно
for field, values in zip(list2, list1):
    # Формируем строку для каждой пары значений
    values_str = ', '.join(values)
    result_str = f'{field}: {values_str}'
    result_list.append(result_str)

# Объединяем все строки в одну строку
result_message = '\n'.join(result_list)

# Выводим результат
print(result_message)
```

Вывод:

```
профиль: значение поля профиль
фамилия: значение поля фамилия
город: значение поля город
```